# How can I change the number of items that end up in a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm hacking away at a rails project and I wanted to modify the number of items that end up on a particular page. The page gets populated via an array of items.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to make it show only 2 instead of 4 items.

In the haml file there is this section:

```
%ul.story-list
- @stories.each do |story|
  %li
    - unless story.image.blank?
      .img-container{ class: ((story.video.blank?)? "": "video-container") }
        = image_tag(story.image_url, alt: story.name, class: ((story.video.blank?)? "": "js-has-video"), :video => story.video)
    .story-data
      %h4= story.name
      %h5.location= story.location
      %p.quote= story.story
      - if story.get_connected?
        = link_to 'Get Connected', connect_path
      - elsif story.gather_supplies?
        = link_to 'Gather Supplies', supplies_path
      - elsif story.make_a_plan?
        = link_to 'Make a plan', plan_path
```

The page shows up (on the server) with four story items, I want it to only show two. I was expecting to open the haml file and just delete some lines (or comment them out). I'm so confused.

So, I suspect the number of stories comes from a controller or something like that. ..but maybe it is coming from the placeholder data on the server?

In case you are inspired to help me, all the code is here
https://github.com/city72/city-72

The exact page I'm trying to modify is this one, I want it to only have two stories:
http://collier72.herokuapp.com/stories

Weirdly, in my local environment I can't edit the stories at all. That's what makes me thing the number of items comes from the data.

The stories controller is this tiny little file that doesn't specify the number of stories:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController

  after_filter :static_content

  def index
    all_stories = EmergencyStory.order("index,id ASC").all
    @selected_story = all_stories.select {|s| s.selected}.first
    @stories = all_stories.collect.select {|s| !s.selected}
  end

end
```

Comment: @stories comes from here app/controllers/stories_controller.rb, it's probably best to change the data you want in the view in the controller

Comment: @nikkypx thanks.. but where does the number of stories come from?

Comment: @nikkypx I pasted the contents of the StoriesController above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up this file:

https://github.com/city72/city-72/blob/master/app/controllers/stories_controller.rb#L8

Change that line from this:

```
@stories = all_stories.collect.select {|s| !s.selected}
```

to this:

```
@stories = all_stories.collect.select{|s| !s.selected}.slice(0,2)
```

From what I can tell, the fact it is returning 4 isn't intentional, it's just what is in the database.  The `slice(0,2)` will return the first two items.

Comment: Awesome! Trying this now. It's tricky because it doesn't show any stories at all on my local server. So, I'll deploy to heroku and see if it worked.

Comment: depends which 2 records you want though

Comment: worked! :) ...if the cms ends up being a little confusing we'll just work around it.

Comment: @pixelfairy Does your local database have any story records in it that match? I bet it doesn't.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom how could I add those records to my local database. ...without totally destroying my local environment. Setting up postgres to run locally without errors was a major hurdle for me on this project.

Comment: @pixelfairy That I can't help with.  Completely depends on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have 3 stories that you are looking for, not 2. You have your `@selected_story` and then the remaining `@stories`. Second, you are retrieving ALL of the stories which will not scale when you get many stories in the database, so rendering this page will slow down over time. So you need to limit the number of records being returned by the database.

Get the selected story.
Then get the two next stories.

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :static_content
  def index
    @selected_story = EmergencyStory.where(selected: true).first
    @stories = EmergencyStory.where(selected: false) # don't get selected
                             .limit(2) # limit records returned
                             .order("index,id ASC")
                             .all
  end
end
```

If you were to further refine this you should put those two queries into methods into `EmergencyStory`.

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :static_content
  def index
    @selected_story = EmergencyStory.selected_story
    @stories = EmergencyStory.recent_stories
  end
end

class EmergencyStory < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.selected_story
     where(selected: true).first
   end

   def self.recent_stories
     where(selected: false).limit(2).order('index,id ASC').all
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go with the risk of slowing down the page (for the moment) since there are a very limited number of people that can add content. ..but I will definitely take this into consideration moving forward.

Comment: @pixelfairy just be aware of the lessons in this post. Let the database do what it is good at: limiting the number of records being returned, sorting, and filtering. By collecting all of the stories you are bringing every story into memory. While your way works, it is not the way you want to do it.

Comment: I agree that it should be changed. I just would want to be working with somebody that knows more than me for that refactoring. ..especially since I don't have good demo data on my local environment.

Comment: I will, however, write a github issue.